# DragSource component disappears when using Yahoo ReactDnD touch backend

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am learning ReactDnD through an example on its documentation page:
(gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/examples-dustbin-single-target.html)

The issue I encountered is that DragSource component disappears when I use ReactDnD touch backend and the DropTarget seems to detect only the dragging event of DropSource.
It works as expected with HTML5 backend.

Demo of the issue (I use dustbin example  from ReactDnD page and only change the example’s source code from HTML5Backend to TouchBackend): https://make2514.github.io/ (Please test this link on mobile device - TouchBackend does not work on desktop browser by default)

I only change
from: export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(EditorApp); (ReactDnD works as expected here)
to: export default DragDropContext(TouchBackend)(EditorApp); ( I encountered the issue above)

Here is my github repo which has source code for the issue:
https://github.com/make2514/Test-TouchBackend-ReactDnD

Question: Would I have to change anything (apart from changing HTML5Backend to TouchBackend) in order for the ReactDnD Dustbin example to work properly on mobile device?

If you could give me some inputs regarding the issue or demos in which ReactDnD with TouchBackend working properly on mobile, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: The above problem causes by: 
- I forgot to implement a CustomDragLayer for my DragSource Component.
- I use the newest version of yahoo touch backend which causes ReactDnD isOver props of my DropTarget to return false all the time (Please refer to this issue for more information: https://github.com/yahoo/react-dnd-touch-backend/issues/34)

Comment: To change the Yahoo touch backend to version 0.2.7, use these commands:
npm remove --save react-dnd-touch-backend &&
npm install --save react-dnd-touch-backend@0.2.7